# Applying Same Excel-VBA Code in All Active Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

In need of help in applying the following code below for all sheets. I have tried the code I found online which is ApplyToAllSheets() but I am still new and I don't know how I can make it work. Please help.

```
Sub ApplyToAllSheets()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Third wks
    Next

End Sub

Sub Third(wks As Worksheet)
Dim Rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim ContainWord As String
    With wks
        Set Rng = .Range(.Range("B1"), .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

'For deleting the remaining informations not necessary
  Set Rng = Range("B1:B1000")
  ContainWord = "-"
  For Each cell In Rng.Cells
    If cell.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then cell.Clear
  Next cell
  Set Rng = Range("C1:C1000")
  ContainWord = "2019" 'change to current year
  For Each cell In Rng.Cells
    If cell.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then cell.Clear
  Next cell
  Set Rng = Range("A1:A1000")
  ContainWord = "-"
  For Each cell In Rng.Cells
    If cell.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then cell.Clear
  Next cell

'For deleting the blanks
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

'For shifting the date to the left
Columns("C").Cut
Columns("A").Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("C").Cut
Columns("B").Insert

'For deleting the negative sign "-"
With Columns("B:B")
    .Replace What:="-", Replacement:=""
End With

End Sub
```

It should successfully apply the code to all the sheets
My result is that the first sheet was always cleared and the other sheets are untouched. please help

Comment: You've got unqualified `Range`  and `Columns` calls, meaning that the `Worksheet` isn't specified. Move that first `End With` all the way to the end and add periods in front of each `Range` and `Columns` instance that doesn't have one.

Comment: @BigBen I cannot seem to understand how to add periods. Could you please show it to me? if its okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got unqualified - meaning the `Worksheet` isn't qualified - `Range` and `Columns` calls.

This is good - note the period in front of each instance of `Range`, as well as before `Rows`.

```
With wks
    Set Rng = .Range(.Range("B1"), .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
```

This, not so much:

```
Set Rng = Range("B1:B1000") ' no worksheet specified, so it's the ActiveSheet, not wks.
```

Or again:

```
Columns("C").Cut
```

Move that first `End With` *all the way* to the end of the `Sub`, and add a period in front of each instance of `Range` and `Columns`. By doing so, they will reference `wks` and not imply the `ActiveSheet`.

While you're at it, change that instance of `ActiveSheet` to `wks`. You want to work with `wks`, not the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: what should i put in "Set Rng = Range("B1:B1000")" in order to apply it to all worksheets

Comment: Once you've moved that `End With`, add a period: `Set Rng = .Range("B1:B1000")`.

Comment: it worked! how about the part in deleting the blanks:
'For deleting the blanks
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
how should I apply it to all worksheets. Thank you very much! you are very helpful and effective

Comment: Change `ActiveSheet` to `wks`. That's the last line in the answer :)

Comment: I have a question, what if I have a blank cell in column A, which looks like 1, 2, 4,5 and I need to fill that blank with the number above it +1? what should i code that's the last thing im going to do

Comment: It should be pretty easy to do, but probably best to ask it in a new question, since it's a different issue.